# Hover em outra imagem ou background

Tags: javascript, html5

Gente é possivel dar hover em outra imagem exemplo

não é oficial mais é tipo assim:

```
<div class='blabla'>
<center><img class='bleble' src='imagem1.jpg'/></center>
<br/>
<a href='/'><img class='blibli' src='imagem2.jpg'/></a> - <a href='/'><img class='bloblo' src='imagem3.jpg'/></a>
<br/><br/>
</div>
```

Quando passa o mouse na imagem 2 e 3 altera a imagem 1 para uma suposta imagem 4, lembrando que a imagem 1 pode estar em background também desde que altere ele quando passa o mouse na 2 ou 3.
Em html ou javascript queria saber se tem como fazer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
$('.blibli,.bloblo').on('mouseover', function() {
  $('.bleble').prop('src', 'https://blognumbers.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/4.jpg');
});

$('.blibli,.bloblo').on('mouseout', function() {
  $('.bleble').prop('src', 'https://blognumbers.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/1.jpg');
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='blabla'>
  <center><img class='bleble' src='https://blognumbers.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/1.jpg'/></center>
  <br/>
  <a href='/'><img class='blibli' src='https://blognumbers.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/2.jpg'/></a> - <a href='/'><img class='bloblo' src='https://blognumbers.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/3.jpg'/></a>
  <br/><br/>
</div>
```

- [MultipleSelector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)
- [MouseOver](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)
- [MouseOut](https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)

Comment: é assim mesmo que eu queria, muito obrigada

Comment: @Lary se a resposta te atendeu marque ela como solução no lado esquerdo, para que outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida possam ser ajudadas!

Comment: ta vou testar aqui primeiro e ja faço isso kkkk